# What are the differences between a Just-in-Time-Compiler and an Interpreter?

Tags: java, .net, compiler-construction, interpreter, jit

What are the differences between a Just-in-Time-Compiler and an Interpreter, and are there differences between the .NET and the Java JIT compiler?

Comment: Your question title doesn't really match the question text.  Both Java and .NET are jitted, neither are interpreted.

Comment: it served as a second question

Comment: then you should ask it as a second, different question. This way you are just confusing people.

Comment: Putting two questions in one is a problem, and putting just one in the title is more so.  People will tend to search on the title, and therefore totally miss your second question.  Looking over the answers as I write, including the two deleted ones, your second question has been completely overlooked.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is the conversion of non-native code, for example bytecode, into native code just before it is executed.

From Wikipedia:

> JIT builds upon two earlier ideas in run-time environments: bytecode compilation and dynamic compilation. It converts code at runtime prior to executing it natively, for example bytecode into native machine code.

An [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) executes a program. It may or may not have a jitter.

Again, from Wikipedia:

> An interpreter may be a program that
>   either
>
> 1. executes the source code directly
> 2. translates source code into some efficient intermediate representation
>      (code) and immediately executes this
> 3. explicitly executes stored precompiled code made by a compiler
>      which is part of the interpreter
>      system

Both the standard Java and .NET distributions have JIT compilation, but it is not required by the standards. The JIT compiler in .NET and C# are of course different because the intermediate bytecode is different. The principle is the same though.

Comment: Does the JIT Compiler of the CLR compiles the WHOLE code once or not?

Comment: No, it compiles only the necessary code. This gives you an atvantage to optimise in a runtime.

Comment: But the optimisation process per call occurs only one time, doesn't it (.NET JIT)? Because I red the .NET JIT compiles a peace of code only one time.

Comment: I would say this can be misleading to someone new to JIT etc. because it does not say explicitly the difference: Interpreter is like  program that uses your source code as a guidelines as to which of "his own" subroutines to call. That is why it is called "interpreter". On the other hand, JIT transforms all your source code directlly to native.

Comment: Isn't point 1 and 3 the same? I mean how would an interpreter execute code without translating it somehow and use something that is already there?

Answer (score 63):

I've always found that a more abstract explanation sometimes helps.
Let's say that you are trying to ask everyone in Mexico "Hello. How are you?" (your **source language**) Of course, you'll first need to translate it to Spanish (the **native language** of the country). That translation would be "Hola. Como estas?"

If you know Spanish, there would be no need for you to translate (**native code / assembler**). You just ask "Hola. Como estas?"

If you don't know Spanish, there are 3 ways to deal with it.

The first is to get a Spanish Dictionary (a **compiler**) and look up what the Spanish words are before you go. Perhaps you realize that "Hola. Que tal?" is one syllable shorter (**compiler optimization**) and use that instead. This is **language compilation**; you are converting the information to the native language beforehand.

The second is where you look up the words in the Spanish Dictionary while you are standing in front of the first person and then store the result (looking up the words **just-in-time**). The advantage here is that you could get a Mandarin Dictionary and then do the same experiment in China without having to keep ten sticky notes (**binaries for different platforms**) of translated phrases.

The third is where you look up the words while you are standing in front of each person. In essence, you interpret the words for each person separately (you act as an **interpreter**). The advantage here is that any changes are instantly reflected with the next person (you could change to asking "Hello. What color is your dog?" without having to fly home and restart - you don't need to **recompile** the phrases).

- Translating beforehand means you can ask people fastest (**pre-compiliation**); you don't need to even bring the dictionary with you.
- Translating when you see the first person in each country is almost as fast as translating beforehand but still allows you to travel to multiple countries without needing to go home to get a dictionary but means that you need to bring several dictionaries with you (**a platform independent runtime**).
- Translating on demand is much slower but allows you to change the words without traveling home (**source distributed language**).

Comment: Awesome, I love this answer. All others are too technical and would confuse non-programmers.

Comment: How would I take advantage of the stored (spanish) result when using Mandarin in China?

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand... As long as I am in Mexico I use the stored result?

Comment: This is an awesome explanation! Just one question though... what is a Source distributed language? I can't find a clear definition of it.

Answer (score 24):

An interpreter generates and executes machine code instructions on the fly for each instruction, regardless of whether it has previously been executed.
A JIT caches the instructions that have been previously interpreted to machine code, and reuses those native machine code instructions thus saving time & resources by not having to re-interpret statements that have already been interpreted.

Comment: Your answer is related to the Java JIT Compiler doesn't it?

Comment: Yup, but I believe that the JIT technique was first developed on smalltalk.

Comment: So a JIT causes a program to get faster the long it runs?

Comment: Not necessarily, because there could be some logic in the program causing it to be slow. The JIT won't change the logic. But at least the cost of CPU cycles that are spent converting the logic to machine code will only be incurred once.

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr

**Interpreter**: takes only one instruction at a time for execution

**Just-in-time**: takes a block of code at once and compile it before execute. so has plenty room for optimization

Comment: so the difference is mostly on code compliation optimization. for JIT, a section of code compiled with optimization, while interpreter doesn't do any optimization.

Answer (score 8):

The question of whether an execution engine is a compiler or an interpreter can be answered very simply by considering what happens if a routine is executed 1,000 times.  If code within the execution engine will have to examine some particular representation of the code 1,000 times, the execution engine is an interpreter of that representation.  If code within the execution the execution engine will only have to examine that particular representation of the code some smaller number of times (typically, though not necessarily, once), it is a compiler or translator of that representation.  Note that it is very common for an execution engine to take input code and convert it to some other form which can be examined more readily.  Such an execution engine would combine a compiler or translator of the former form with an interpreter of the latter form.

Note that interpreters very seldom produce any form of machine code.  Just about the only time an interpreter will produce machine code is when a statement is supposed to perform some operation that really cannot be done any other way.  For example, if a BASIC interpreter running on the 8080 encounters the instruction "OUT 100,5", it would typically perform that operation by storing D3 64 C9 (OUT 64h / RET) into three consecutive bytes at some fixed address, loading A with 5, and CALLing that address.  The interpreter may technically be generating machine code, but if one were to perform the same OUT instruction 500 times, the interpreter would have to re-generate the machine code every time.

Answer (score 3):

JIT compiler produces binary machine codes translating block source code. Interpreter translates line by line.

Answer (score 1):

When the first time a class is referenced the JIT Execution Engine re-compiles the .class files (primary Binaries) generated by Java Compiler containing JVM Instruction Set to Binaries containing HOST system’s Instruction Set. JIT stores and reuses those recompiled binaries from Memory going forward, there by reducing interpretation time and benefits from Native code execution.

On the other hand a plain old java interpreter interprets one JVM instruction from class file at a time and calls a procedure against it.

Find a detail comparison here http://bitshub.blogspot.com/2010/01/Flavors-of-JVM.html

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a Microsoft.NET language, the complier generates code written in the Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). MSIL is a set of instructions that can quickly be translated into native code.

A Microsoft.NET application can be run only after the MSIL code is translated into native machine code. In .NET Framework, the intermediate language is complied "just in time" (JIT) into native code when the application or component is run instead of compiling the application at development time.

[more info](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/jit.html)